# Can Android databinding getters return specific fields dynamically based on the getter's argument?

Tags: java, android, observable, android-databinding, bindable

The compiler throws a build exception *@Bindable associated with method must follow JavaBeans convention* related to a getter that's marked @Bindable, which accepts one parameter (*phototag*) and returns a specific field's value based on that parameter value:

```
private boolean operationPhotoSaved;
private boolean material1PhotoSaved;
private boolean material2PhotoSaved;
private boolean material3PhotoSaved;
private boolean material4PhotoSaved;
private boolean material5PhotoSaved;

@Bindable
public boolean isPhotoSaved (PhotoTag photoTag){
    boolean isSaved = false;
    switch (photoTag) {
        case OPERATIONPHOTO:
            isSaved = this.operationPhotoSaved;
            break;
        case MATERIAL1PHOTO:
            isSaved = this.material1PhotoSaved;
            break;
        case MATERIAL2PHOTO:
            isSaved = this.material2PhotoSaved;
            break;
        case MATERIAL3PHOTO:
            isSaved = this.material3PhotoSaved;
            break;
        case MATERIAL4PHOTO:
            isSaved = this.material4PhotoSaved;
            break;
        case MATERIAL5PHOTO:
            isSaved = this.material5PhotoSaved;
            break;
    }
    return isSaved;
}
```

It seems this is not allowed in Android data-binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually avoided the error by creating standard getters and setters for each field and set the @Bindable mark to the getters while removing it from the *isPhotoSaved* method, then call the getters from within that method:

```
private boolean operationPhotoSaved;
private boolean material1PhotoSaved;
private boolean material2PhotoSaved;
private boolean material3PhotoSaved;
private boolean material4PhotoSaved;
private boolean material5PhotoSaved;
private boolean videoSaved;


public boolean isPhotoSaved(PhotoTag photoTag) {
    boolean isSaved = false;
    switch (photoTag) {
        case OPERATIONPHOTO:
            isSaved = isOperationPhotoSaved();
            break;
        case MATERIAL1PHOTO:
            isSaved = isMaterial1PhotoSaved();
            break;
        case MATERIAL2PHOTO:
            isSaved = isMaterial2PhotoSaved();
            break;
        case MATERIAL3PHOTO:
            isSaved = isMaterial3PhotoSaved();
            break;
        case MATERIAL4PHOTO:
            isSaved = isMaterial4PhotoSaved();
            break;
        case MATERIAL5PHOTO:
            isSaved = isMaterial5PhotoSaved();
            break;
    }
    return isSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isOperationPhotoSaved() {
    return operationPhotoSaved;
}

public void setOperationPhotoSaved(boolean operationPhotoSaved) {
    this.operationPhotoSaved = operationPhotoSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isMaterial1PhotoSaved() {
    return material1PhotoSaved;
}

public void setMaterial1PhotoSaved(boolean material1PhotoSaved) {
    this.material1PhotoSaved = material1PhotoSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isMaterial2PhotoSaved() {
    return material2PhotoSaved;
}

public void setMaterial2PhotoSaved(boolean material2PhotoSaved) {
    this.material2PhotoSaved = material2PhotoSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isMaterial3PhotoSaved() {
    return material3PhotoSaved;
}

public void setMaterial3PhotoSaved(boolean material3PhotoSaved) {
    this.material3PhotoSaved = material3PhotoSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isMaterial4PhotoSaved() {
    return material4PhotoSaved;
}

public void setMaterial4PhotoSaved(boolean material4PhotoSaved) {
    this.material4PhotoSaved = material4PhotoSaved;
}

@Bindable
public boolean isMaterial5PhotoSaved() {
    return material5PhotoSaved;
}

public void setMaterial5PhotoSaved(boolean material5PhotoSaved) {
    this.material5PhotoSaved = material5PhotoSaved;
}
```